# Is it a valid argument?

Tags: logic, argumentation, validity, reason

I wonder if the below argument is a valid or invalid?

```
Premise 1: All the humans can fly
Premise 2: I am a human
---------------------------------
Conclusion: Therefore, I can fly
```

I also wonder, if that form of argument is a valid argument, then where is the problem, soundness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid argument - if the premises were true, the conclusion would also be true. However, premise 1 is not true, so the argument is unsound.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Sofie Selnes is right.  You can obey all the rules of logic in the argument, but if you have bad axioms, the conclusion can be questioned.